# Play 2.1 error exception when typing play.Project.jdbc class file needed by PlayReloader is missing

Tags: playframework-2.1

trouble running, cleaning or playing, starting play2.1 app. I can create the app, but then if i try to run, clean, play or start. i get this error

exception when typing play.Project.jdbc
class file needed by PlayReloader is missing.

any thoughts would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

turned out to be a permissions issue. the app had lost its executable permission. no clue how it happened